# jquery ajax not callback when header is in the posted page

Tags: jquery, ajax

When i try to ajax post, the second page containing header which causes the page to get status code '0'.

Now, i have to load google page in index in some section or any div.
Our target is to get the header loaded file too.

index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<p class="result">Click me too!</p>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'sub2.php',
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
$(".result").load("sub2.php");
    },
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("status:"+jqXHR.status);
    alert("text:"+textStatus);
    alert("thrown:"+errorThrown);
    $(".result").load("sub2.php");
},
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

sub2.php page;

```
<?php

echo "hello";
header("location:https://google.com");

?>
```

Comment: remove echo statement from first line.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work :

```
<?php

echo "hello";
header("location:https://google.com");

?>
```

In the manual :

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Comment: Thanks @Sly, But, when i try to access the sub2.php page, it redirects to google correctly.  page is working fine. In index ajax calls, callback function shows error.  But, i need to get google page as data.

Comment: maybe it would be better to use php's file_get_contents(...) ?

Comment: Thanks sly, helps in someway.